# Migrate TFS 2008 Project Portal Contents to TFS 2010 Project Portal

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

I have established a large amount of content (mainly document libraries) on my TFS 2008 project portal, and have been forced to upgrade to TFS 2010 recently.  I would like to move as much content to the new portal as possible, but it sounds like its very difficult with the amount of changes they made between versions.  Any suggestions or references would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching further, the only way I came up with was to manually move the structure over to the 2010 site.  I literally opened up both sites in Windows Explorer and copied the whole structure of each document library over.